# Narrow convergence of probability measures with a not bounded function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $ (\nu_n)_{\mathbb{N}} $ be a sequecence of Borel probability measure on $ [0,1]\times\mathbb{R} $ such that $$\nu_n\rightarrow\nu_{\infty} \text{ narrowly},$$
i.e. for every bounded continuous function $ h\in\mathcal{C}_b([0,1]\times\mathbb{R})$
$$ \int_{[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}}h(x,y)\ d\nu_n(x,y)\rightarrow\int_{[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}}h(x,y)\ d\nu_{\infty}(x,y) $$
where $ \nu_{\infty} $ is also a probability measure.

I know that for each measure $\nu_n$ with $ n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\} $ we have that
$$ \int_{[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}}y\ d\nu_n(x,y)<+\infty.$$
I would say that
$$ \int_{[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}}y\ d\nu_n(x,y)\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_{[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}}y\ d\nu_{\infty}.$$
It is true? I think that the tightness condition could help, but I failed to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables converging almost surely to $0$ such that $EX_n$ does not tend to $0$. (Example: $X_n=nI_{(0,\frac 1n)}$ on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure). Let $\nu_n=m \times \mu_n$ and $\nu=m \times \mu$ where $\mu_n$ is the law of $X_n$ and $\mu$ is the law of $0$ (i.e. $\mu =\delta_0$). Then you can check that $\nu_n \to \nu$ but $\int yd\nu_n =1$ for all $n$ and $\int yd\nu=0$.